# Azure kubernetes - Can it spread across multiple zones?

Tags: azure, azure-aks

As per the Microsoft documentation, Azure kubernetes supports availability zones however I wonder if it Can spread across multiple Azure regions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it can, as per the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/availability-zones#:%7E:text=AKS%20clusters%20that%20are%20deployed,zones%20in%20East%20US%202.)

> By defining node pools in a cluster to span multiple zones, nodes in a
> given node pool are able to continue operating even if a single zone
> has gone down. Your applications can continue to be available even if
> there is a physical failure in a single datacenter if orchestrated to
> tolerate failure of a subset of nodes.

Comment: Thank you, Sajeetharan. Would it support multiple Azure regions?

Comment: No multiple regions are not supported, you need to have a secondary cluster

Comment: Go through this doc https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/aks/operator-best-practices-multi-region